# client_side_validations - How to reset form errors and style if valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, client-side-validation

I am using the client_side_validations gem.

- How can I change styles if valid or if it is passed?
- How can I remove or reset all form errors?

Comment: I cannot figure out how the https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/wiki/Callbacks are supposed to work.

Comment: How to activate the callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

You have to over write the callback specifically. A good example is with the DockYard website: https://github.com/dockyard/dockyard.com/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/rails.validations.callbacks.js